# Reset Prefix in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a command with a default prefix to reset the current prefix of my bot.

```
@bot.command()
async def prefix(ctx, arg):
  bot.command_prefix = arg
  await ctx.send("You prefix has been updated to: "+str(arg))

@bot.event()
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith("-reset"):
    bot.command_prefix = "-"
    await ctx.send("You prefix has been reseted to: -")
```

When I execute it, only the `bot.event()` part works. I don´t get any error, but the bot.command() code just doesn't work

Comment: Why are you using `bot.command` and in-on_message commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `@bot.event` blocks the other commands unless you add  `await bot.process_commands(message)` in the end.

Here is your corrected code.

```py
@bot.command()
async def prefix(ctx, arg):
  bot.command_prefix = arg
  await ctx.send("Your prefix has been updated to: "+str(arg))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == bot.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith("-reset"):
    bot.command_prefix = "-"
    await message.channel.send("Your prefix has been reset")
  await bot.process_commands(message)
```